# How can I read how many lives are remaining in Super Mario Bros. 2 (JPN)?

Tags: super-mario-bros-the-lost-levels

I'm playing the GBA version of *SMB2 JPN* (also known as *The Lost Levels*). This game is hard! So I cheat and get more lives. And I do, but after I get more than 10, the "Lives Remaining" count is some weird sprite and not a number (the SNES version seems to correct this). For example, 15 lives [look like](http://www.gamefaqs.com/famicomds/916579-super-mario-bros-2-japan/faqs/32060) a "Crown" and a "5".

I want to know: what does "Lives Remaining" look like when I have more than 10? Pictures, please.

Answer (score 3):

via [gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii/939288-super-mario-bros-the-lost-levels/faqs/32060):

> ... starting with 10 lives, the life 
>   counter will be glitchy. From 10-19
>   lives, you will see a crown followed
>   by  the ones digit; for example, if
>   you have 15 lives, the counter will
>   display a  crown followed by 5. From
>   20-45 lives, the ones digit is a
>   letter instead; to  find out the
>   number of lives you have, take the
>   numerical value of the letter  (A = 1,
>   B = 2, C = 3 ... Z = 26) and add 19.
>   For example, a crown followed by  D is
>   19 + 4, or 23 lives. If you have 46 or
>   more lives, the ones digit is a  weird
>   symbol, usually chunks of other
>   pictures that exist in the game.

Comment: Heh, I already linked that document. :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the link.